# Marine Corps Muster Roll abbreviations

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, military-records, navy

my question is similar to [What is the meaning of these remarks on 1948 USMC discharge papers?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-remarks-on-1948-usmc-discharge-papers) but with different abbreviations that I can't find the answer to. Below is the transcription I have. I know fur is furlough but not sure about "das", "B&W" , "CO", "OH", and "fr conf." Thinking "das" could be days, "B&W" bread and water, "CO" Commanding Officer, "OH" Operational Headquarters but not exactly sure.

> 1-6, fur; 16, red and awd five (5) das on B&W by CO at OH for: "Intoxication"; 21,fr conf; 22-29, fur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [MARINE CORPS INDIVIDUAL RECORDS ADMINISTRATION MANUAL (SHORT TITLE: IRAM)](http://www.marines.mil/Portals/59/Publications/MCO%20P1070.12K%20W%20CH%201.pdf) is one good reference for some of these. CHAPTER 6 ABBREVIATIONS AND ACRONYMS begins on (actual document) Pg.# 6-3 (177 of 259 in PDF) and continues on to the list a few pages later.

das - DAYS

B&W - BREAD-WATER

CO - COMMANDING OFFICER

OH - OPERATIONAL HANDBOOK

fr - FROM

conf - CONFIDENTIAL

Comment: I agree with your assessment that OH would have been Operations Headquarters.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering if there was a book/manual somewhere because the places I had found some just weren't official.

Answer (score 0):

‘OH’ stands for ‘Office Hours’ a term for non-judicial punishment administered by the organization’s Commanding Officer. Judicial punishment is referred to a court-martial.