# Female WW2 U.S. Marine Corps Muster Rolls

Tags: 20th-century, military-records, world-war-2, jewish

in my Great Grandmother's United States Marine Corps muster roll record the following information appears to be provided:

**055 1-17  & 19...30, D, FPOSF;
18, only, sk qtrs.**

How do I interpret this?

[image: MUSTER ROLL IMAGE]

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full answer, but this is too much like an answer to be a comment.

FPOSF is Fleet Post Office, San Francisco, where she would have received her mail.

1-17 & 19-30, combined with 18 only, look like days of a month.

On the 18th only, she was "sk qtrs" or "sick in quarters."

An [answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3773/10577) to [Marine Corps Muster Roll abbreviations](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/marine-corps-muster-roll-abbreviations) may help with some of the rest.